# Array of Objects somehow turns into a function when mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my state, I a property called `UrlItems` which is an array of objects.

I call `addUrlItem('www.google.com')`

This will create a new object and with the properties id, url, status

```
addUrlItem = (url) => {
    let { UrlItems } = this.state
    let id = UrlItems.length

    let props = {
        id,
        url,
        status: statusTypes.IDLE
    }

    UrlItems.push(props)
    this.setState({UrlItems})

}
```

In one of my render methods, I am trying to map through the array and set a component.

```
renderUrlItems() {

    let { UrlItemsRendered, UrlItems } = this.state

    UrlItemsRendered = UrlItems.map((item, key) => {
        return (<UrlItem {...item} remove={this.removeUrlItem} statusTypes={statusTypes}></UrlItem>)
    })

    return UrlItemsRendered
}
```

When I console log the `item` in the map function, it tells me it is not an object but a function

Here is what my Console looks like when I console log the state object

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but `.push()` is altering state without using `setState`

Comment: I've updated my code. I could probably remove UrlItemsRendered from the state object since I am returning it

Comment: you are still editing the state directly. you are using the same `UrlItemsRendered` to get the values from the state (reference) and setting a new map (UrlItems.map)